# undefined variables for grafana dashboard deployed via ansible

Tags: ansible, dashboard, grafana

I deploy grafana role and dashboards on k8s server via ansible

my-dashboard.json.yml.j2

dashboard file has variable for target legendFormat

looks like

```
"legendFormat": "{{ pod }}"
```

when this is commented all installed correctly, but dont show required legend on dashboard

How can I get to work variable on dashboard and ignore it for ansible during deploy manifest?